# parse csv file embedded in javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, python-requests, lxml

I am not sure if the title is appropriate description of what i intend to do. However, below is the url from where I want to parse the csv file in python (the csv handle is visible on the top right corner of the interactive table).

https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/bhavcopy

I have parsed files before using `Requests` and `lxml` but in those cases the address (or location) of the `csv` file was rather straightforward. In this case, I am not able to ascertain the actual url location of the file. Although rudimentary, my assessment is that it is embedded in javascript code. My question is whether I can indeed parse files such as this? if yes, how using`requests` and `lxml`

This is public data and a very inefficient alternative is to download the data daily and than parse the locally stored `csv` file but that is no automation. Any suggestion on how can i automate this task will be very valuable.

Comment: If you view the page source and scroll down a bit, you'll see that the data is stored in `<script>` section as JSON. It's also conveniently marked by `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>`. So you just need to copy everything between those tags, eliminate the `var vTick=`, and then use a JSON reader to parse the rest.